# android http post response format type different than specified in query string

Tags: android

I am sending post request from android to the url using httpclient like this one below -

String url = "http://www.myurl.com/test.php?format=json";

Now I am getting response back in form of plist instead of json, which is default type of response from php file if no format query string is described in url.

Can we specify query string in url while posting? It looks like php file is not getting format query string.

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("method", "add"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("device_id", "123"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("device_token", "3221"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("session_id", "1212"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("event_id","12345" ));

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);                      httppost.addHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
httppost.addHeader("Accept","application/json");
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

/* Checking response */
if (response != null) {
     InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
     String a = convertStreamToString(in);
    Log.i("Read from Server "+response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(), a);
}else{
    Log.i("response is ", "null");

}
```

Thanks

Comment: None of your server code has any handling for a "format" parameter. Where exactly in your PHP is the code supposed that's supposed to return json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to know without seeing your server code, but your server may not like that you're combining HTTP POST parameters in your request body with GET parameters in the URL. Try putting

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("format","json" ));
```

into the section where you're building up the request parameters instead and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for replying ....I have tried putting nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("format","json" )) plist format with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my server code

```
<?php
error_reporting( E_ALL );
ini_set( 'display_errors', 'on' );

if (file_exists("lib")) {
require_once('lib/CFPropertyList-1.0.4/CFPropertyList.php');
include_once("lib/iCon_db_manager.php");
include_once("lib/iConLib.php");
} else {
require_once('../lib/CFPropertyList-1.0.4/CFPropertyList.php');
include_once("../lib/iCon_db_manager.php");
include_once("../lib/iConLib.php");
}

global $_POST;

$method = $_POST["method"];
$event_id = $_POST["event_id"];
if (isset($_POST["session_id"])) {
$session_id = $_POST["session_id"];
}
$device_id = $_POST["device_id"];
$device_token = $_POST["device_token"];

if (strcmp($method, "add") &&
strcmp($method, "delete") &&
strcmp($method, "show")) {
retStatus(1, "Invalid method. Allowed values are add/delete/show");
exit;
}

if (!isset($event_id) || !isset($device_id) || !isset($device_token)) {
retStatus(1, "Event ID, Device ID and Device Token are required");
exit;
}

$scheduleInfo["event_id"] = $event_id;
$scheduleInfo["device_id"] = $device_id;
$scheduleInfo["device_token"] = $device_token;

if (!isset($session_id)) {
// if session_id is not specified either the method is show alerts
$session_id = "";
}
if ($session_id != "") {
$scheduleInfo["session_id"] = $session_id;
}

$iConDBMgr = new iConDBManager();
if (!strcmp($method, "add")) {
if ($session_id == "") {
retStatus(1, "Session ID is required for add");
exit;
}
$schedule = $iConDBMgr->getRecord('iconmyschedule', $scheduleInfo);
if (count($schedule) == 0) {
$iConDBMgr->insertRecord('iconmyschedule', $scheduleInfo);
retStatus(0, "Success");
exit;
} else {
retStatus(2, "You already have this item in your schedule");
exit;
}
} else if (!strcmp($method, "delete")) {
$iConDBMgr->deleteRecord('iconmyschedule', $scheduleInfo);
retStatus(0, "Success");
exit;
} else {
$items = $iConDBMgr->getRecord('iconmyschedule', $scheduleInfo);
$plist = new CFPropertyList();
$plist->add( $dict = new CFDictionary() );
$dict->add( 'event_id', new CFString($event_id));
$dict->add( 'device_id', new CFString($device_id));
$dict->add( 'device_token', new CFString($device_token));
$dict->add('sessions', $sessArray = new CFArray());

if (count($items) != 0) {
foreach ($items as $item) {
$sessArray->add(new CFString($item{"session_id"}));
}
}
retResult($plist);
}
```

?>

Comment: This should be added to your question, not posted as an answer.